# Poem source and English translation - 愿无岁月可回头，且敬往事一杯酒

Tags: translation, meaning

I am interested in this poem (shown below). Unfortunately I don't know much about where it originates. It seems to be posted frequently online but the original author / source is omitted.

Mostly I've read this using translation tools but if a proper English translation exists, I'd love to read it.

愿无岁月可回头，且敬往事一杯酒
看流年似水，往事不可追
愿你
每天那么忙
做的都是自己喜欢的
此后做的每一个选择都是为了自己
少一些何必当初，多一些暗自庆幸
以后的所有泪水，都是喜极而泣 
昨天已经过去
无论怎样忧伤，都无济于事
时间不会倒流，光阴不会倒转
明天尚未到来，无论怎样期待
最终能否如愿，都是个未知数
只有今天才真正属于自己
有些路，走下去
会很累，但是不走，会后悔
人生没有对错，只有选择后的坚持
不后悔，走下去，就是对的
喜欢一句诗，走着走着，花就开了
人生就像坐火车一样
过去的景色那样美，让你流连不舍
可是你总是需要前进，会离开
然后你告诉自己，没关系
我以后一定还会再来看
可其实，往往你再也不会回去
流逝的时间，退后的风景
邂逅的人，终究是渐行渐远
亲爱的自己
不要抓住过去不放
断了线的风筝让它飞
放过它，更是放过自己
你的孤独，虽败犹荣
愿无岁月可回头，且敬往事一杯酒

Comment: What is your question? To ask whether English translation exists online or to ask someone translate this poem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can't find an author. Frequently these articles are created by the internet PR business, or what we call 营销号. They steal materials from various sources and stitch them together to create click-baits.

Sorry if this sounds harsh, but this piece is far from good literature. You find much better verses in Reader's Digest. But still, it took me some minutes to do the translation. Please ignore the rough edges because I only had 15 minutes for it:

```
看流年似水，往事不可追
Watching the seasons pass like a river. What's happened cannot be undone.
愿你
Wish you
每天那么忙
Busy everyday
做的都是自己喜欢的
doing what you love to do
此后做的每一个选择都是为了自己
Every choice you make from now on, are made for yourself
少一些何必当初，多一些暗自庆幸
Fewer regrets, more secret rejoice
以后的所有泪水，都是喜极而泣
From now on, all your tears are tears of happiness. 
昨天已经过去
Yesterday has passed
无论怎样忧伤，都无济于事
However sad you are, it wouldn't help
时间不会倒流，光阴不会倒转
Time don't flow backwards, day and night don't reverse themselves
明天尚未到来，无论怎样期待
Tomorrow is yet to come, whatever you expect
最终能否如愿，都是个未知数
may or may not come true, nobody knows
只有今天才真正属于自己
What you really have is today
有些路，走下去
Some roads, if you walk on
会很累，但是不走，会后悔
you will be exhausted, but if you dont, you will regret
人生没有对错，只有选择后的坚持
There is no right or wrong in life, only stick to your chice
不后悔，走下去，就是对的
Don't regret, keep on, that's it
喜欢一句诗，走着走着，花就开了
There is a line I like: You walk on and on, then the flowers begin to bloom.
人生就像坐火车一样
Life is like a journey on a train
过去的景色那样美，让你流连不舍
You see beautiful scenes, you don't want to let go
可是你总是需要前进，会离开
But you have to move forward, have to leave,
然后你告诉自己，没关系
Then you tell yourself: it's OK,
我以后一定还会再来看
I'll be back someday
可其实，往往你再也不会回去
But in fact, the chances are you will never be back
流逝的时间，退后的风景
Time passes, scenes retreat
邂逅的人，终究是渐行渐远
Whoever you get to know, will eventually part their ways
亲爱的自己
Dear self:
不要抓住过去不放
Don't cling to the past
断了线的风筝让它飞
Let the loose kite fly away
放过它，更是放过自己
Let it go, moreover, let go of yourself
你的孤独，虽败犹荣
Your loneliness, though defeated, is not without glory
愿无岁月可回头，且敬往事一杯酒
May there be no years and months worthy of going back, and let's raise the glasses for what happened in the past.
```

Comment: Thanks for the translation and source explanation, I was wondering if that was the case. It made me curious as I had found many variations but didn't know why.